# CKEditor5 - Append content at curosr position of editor with react

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

Append the content at the cursor position in ckeditor 5 with React. I am referring code from below URL -

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html

Answer (score 4):

Grab the editor instance in [`onInit()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#component-properties) and save a reference to it:

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
    onInit={ editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
    } }
    // ...
/>
```

Then, use the editor API to insert the content:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    writer.insertText( 'Plain text', editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition() );
} );
```

Check out more [insertion examples](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#where-are-the-editorinserthtml-and-editorinserttext-methods-how-to-insert-some-content) in the project's FAQ.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
In my code, I am using setState method to assign content state in react then using as data={this.state.content || ""} in CKEditor. When I am assigning writer to content this.setState({
content: writer
});                     It's breaking app please suggest CKEditor with React. You can refer React TextEditor code from - github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/102